# Ошибка Node JS при запуске команды Gulp watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

До установки Open Server на ноут всё было в порядке с node.js, а после я уже не могу вызвать команду npm из командной строки http://joxi.ru/D2Pe16ZCxLv8A3

Answer (score 1):

Оу! )) Это класическая ошибка! Скорее всего Open Server занял порт который пытается использовать gulp. Попробуйте убить пока Open Server и проверить или запустите `netstat -ano` и увидите какой процесс занимает порт.